# Need advice about right React/Redux usage

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example we have state S1 in our items reducer like this:

`| - Item1 - Item1.1
|         - Item1.2
| - Item2
| - Item3 - Item3.1
          - Item3.2
          - Item3.3`

And every item has own state property (open/closed).
We have component that perfectly render this state and everything is ok.

Then we need add one more level of abstraction here, Groups. 
We implement it as function and get new state:

S2 = f(S1)

S2, for example, look like this:

`| - Group1 - Item3.1
|          - Item1.2
| - Group2 - Item2`

We would like render it with the same component but Group1, Group2 need own state (value of open/closed property) and not clear where should be stored this state in terms of Redux.

Thanks in advance for any ideas/recommendations.

Comment: It's not clear what items and groups are, and how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it would be too complicated to store the state in the same shape as your UI. I would keep track of whatever the parent is on each item, with parent key:

```
items: [
  { name: 'Item 1', parent: 'Group 2' },
  { name: 'Item 2.3', parent: 'Group 4' }
]
```

Then you could just filter them in the UI based on the name of the UI component. Given a component that you call `'Group 2'`, you could just use `filter` to find the ones you want:

```
items.filter(item => item.parent === 'Group 2')
```

Of course this is just pseudo-ish code. You could setup a stateless component that took items and a parent name that could be reused everywhere.

Let me know if I'm pointing you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for answer. If I understand you your idea, you mean add information about groups (properties _group_ and _open_ in state S2) in my state initial state S1 and process it with some smart filter. Actually, I think it will work and my idea was sretty similar (keep information about groups in the same state but separate of _items_). Just seems like this solution "smells" not very good and why I decided ask community about better ideas.

Comment: I would argue that this is a trivial problem and there may not be a better way to handle it. You have a group of items that needs to be sorted and organized. You either keep track of where it belongs on the item and keep the items in a large collection, or break into smaller collections with the items that belong to them. Doing either or and filtering them is pretty normal practice.

Comment: As Tyrsius asked, are there any other relations these items have with each other?

Comment: Yes, items have parent-child relationship and _group by_ is one of representations this structure. In both states items can be updated. So, representation state is update is something that Redux do perfectly. In my case state should be transformed (means S2 = f(S1)) then both should have items consistent, but new entities _groups_ have own state that is tricky.